# How to set scrollView with minimal scale at start?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming, scale

I have to set `UIScrollView` at start with 0.28 `scale` (current scale). How can i do it correclty?

Now to scaling I'm using this methods:

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate Methods

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
return imageView;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
[self centerScrollViewContent];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {

}

- (void)centerScrollViewContent {
CGSize boundsSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;
CGRect contentsFrame = imageView.frame;

if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
    contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
} else {
    contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
}

if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
    contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
} else {
    contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
}

imageView.frame = contentsFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After** your scrollView content is loaded, you can set the zoom scale with:

```
self.scrollView.zoomScale = 0.28;
```

Comment: Thank you ;) That was so simple.